# Using IF with ROUNDDOWN, To Calculate How Many Times For A Process

Tags: excel, calculation

I apologize if the title is a bit vague. I am trying to create a calculator that takes into account how much "scrap" I have, how much is needed to resmelt it, and how many bars recieved.

Currently using:

```
(=if((amtOwned/qtyToSmelt)<1,,rounddown((amtOwned/qtyToSmelt)*barsMade))
```

[Table and Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf0VK.png)

The problem I am having is you MUST have the QTY to Smelt. But the value returned includes partial quantities.
Ex. 125 Bottle Caps should equal 4 Bars total. Yet it returns 5.

How can i make the formula only account for increments of the bars recieved?

Thank you for any help, again i apologize if this isn't that clear. Im not exactly sure how to express my need in this situation.

I have tried messing around with the syntax and where every argument sits, even this formula is the most recent iteration of what i thought would be needed.

EDIT: I have tried using the TRUNC function and this seems to be working as I need it to. The formula now is:

`=TRUNC((AMTowned/AMTneeded),0)*barsRecieved`

`=TRUNC((136/50),0)*2` This is returning 2 bars instead of 3. Which is exactly what I need.

It appears this is working by truncating the number first then multiplying it. So, 1.5 becomes 1 before being multiplied. This was my guess after doing more research. I had been searching for a while before I posted this but am glad to have learned what I have in searching for this.

Comment: Are you asking how to change the formula to get something different? What is the mathematical formula be if you want it different?

Comment: The formula is working correctly to return (QTY/NEEDED)*BARSmade. However I need it to see the amount needed and only add to the total of bars made if it meets the threshold. 
For example, 125(QTYowned)/50(amtNEEDED)*2(BARSmade) returns 5. because 125/50 = 2.5 *2 = 5. I need it to return 4 because thats how many times i can ACTUALLY complete the process to make bars.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for auditing formulas. To see it go to Formulas > Evaluate Formula.
[image]

So here is you formula `=IF((E3/C3)<1,,ROUNDDOWN((E3/C3)*D3,0))`
Have you tried the calculation on your regular calculator? To me it is doing what you would expect. `(125/50)*2 = 5`

Comment: Yes I understand. The math is correct. However i physically can not recieve 5 from the transaction itself because 50 is needed total each time. So 125 should still return 4 until the number owned = 150. then from 150 to 199 a total of 6 should be returned.